# Determining the distance to the origin from three points on a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, least-squares

### Scenario:

A measuring tool consists of a round measuring bung (red circle) equipped with three probes (labeled $a$, $b$, and $c$). These probes are evenly spaced at angles of $120^\circ$ from each other ($\theta = 120^\circ$).

The master part (blue circle), in which the measuring bung is seated, has a known inner bore diameter of $D$. Refer to the diagram below (figure 1):

[image]

However, it is important to note that **the provided diagram does NOT accurately represent the real-world situation**. In practical terms, it is nearly impossible to mount each probe perfectly tangential to the measuring bung. Consequently, each probe is mounted at a unique and unknown starting distance from the center of the measuring bung. These starting distances are denoted as $r_a$, $r_b$, and $r_c$ for probes $a$, $b$, and $c$, respectively. For a clearer representation, please refer to the revised diagram below (figure 2):

[image]

> The following variables are **known**:
>
> - $a$, $b$, $c$ - the distances measured by the 3 probes
> - $\theta$ - the probe mounting angle around the center of the    measuring bung
> - $D$ - the bore diameter of the master part
>
> The following variables are **unknown**:
>
> - $r_a$, $r_b$, $r_c$ - the probe mounting distances from the center ofthe measuring bung

### Objective:

The objective is to find $r_a$, $r_b$, and $r_c$. These distances will be determined during the calibration process (using the master part). Once these distances are determined, the master part can be replaced with a new part having an unknown diameter, such that the diameter of any part can be accurately measured.

### Measurement Process:

The calibration process involves taking any number of measurements $(K)$ with the tooling seated in various configurations. Each time, the tooling was seated in a new position. Using CAD software, I can determine the probe measurements ($a_k, b_k, c_k$) for each measurement $(K)$.

$D = 25.0;$
$R = 12.5;$
$θ = 120^\circ;$

$K=01 :\qquad   a_{01} = 5.2491254 ;\quad  b_{01} = 3.6421203 ;\quad  c_{01} = 5.5479800 ;$
$K=02 :\qquad   a_{02} = 3.5261623 ;\quad  b_{02} = 4.0069957 ;\quad  c_{02} = 6.9097135 ;$
$K=03 :\qquad   a_{03} = 5.2425714 ;\quad  b_{03} = 2.2366199 ;\quad  c_{03} = 6.9231890 ;$
$K=04 :\qquad   a_{04} = 5.6053228 ;\quad  b_{04} = 4.0762025 ;\quad  c_{04} = 4.5958384 ;$
$K=05 :\qquad   a_{05} = 2.6211544 ;\quad  b_{05} = 4.3330685 ;\quad  c_{05} = 7.3330685 ;$
$K=06 :\qquad   a_{06} = 5.6305936 ;\quad  b_{06} = 1.7881182 ;\quad  c_{06} = 6.8966301 ;$
$K=07 :\qquad   a_{07} = 3.1218340 ;\quad  b_{07} = 5.3989306 ;\quad  c_{07} = 5.7511286 ;$
$K=08 :\qquad   a_{08} = 2.8136425 ;\quad  b_{08} = 3.7336225 ;\quad  c_{08} = 7.7652347 ;$
$K=09 :\qquad   a_{09} = 6.7312779 ;\quad  b_{09} = 1.6301678 ;\quad  c_{09} = 5.7985227 ;$
$K=10 :\qquad  a_{10} = 3.7744161 ;\quad  b_{10} = 5.6724511 ;\quad  c_{10} = 4.7375570 ;$

[image]

Find $r_a; r_b;r_c;$ (Prove that $r_a = 8;r_b = 9;r_c = 6;$ for this example)

### Solution based on answers from Fedja

This is my understanding on the solution provided by Fedja... from the perspective of a learner. If you are reading this and you are not Fedja, I recommend you read his answer instead of this.

We will deploy the least-squares method to find numerical approximations of the $r_a$ , $r_b$, and $r_c$.

Let's establish a few important functions:

1. A mathematical expression for the radius, in terms of the variables a,b,c,ra,rb, and rc. I recommend referring to the answer provided by Joshua Wang for a detailed understanding.
   $R=\sqrt{\frac{\left(x^2+y^2+xy\right)\left(x^2+z^2+xz\right)\left(y^2+z^2+yz\right)}{3x^2y^2+3x^2z^2+3y^2z^2+6x^2yz+6{xy}^2z+6xyz^2}}$
2. The mean quadratic error G.
   This function returns the square root of the sum of the squared errors for each measurement point $(k)$. It provides a measure of how well the given guess ($r_a$, $r_b$, $r_c$) fits the measurements. This is the function that is being minimized in order to find the values of  $r_a, r_b$ and $r_c$ that provides the best fit to the given measurements.
   $G\ =\ \sqrt{\frac{1}{K}\ \sum_{k=0}^{K}\left(Error_k\right)^2}$
   Where,
   $K$ is the number of measurements.
   $Error_k=\sqrt{\frac{\left({x_k}^2+{y_k}^2+x_k\ast y_k\right)\left({x_k}^2+{z_k}^2+x_kz_k\right)\left({y_k}^2+{z_k}^2+y_kz_k\right)}{3{x_k}^2{y_k}^2+3{x_k}^2{z_k}^2+3{y_k}^2{z_k}^2+6{x_k}^2y_kz_k+6x_k{y_k}^2z+6\ast x_ky_k{z_k}^2}}-R$
   Where
   $x_k=a_k+r_a $
   $y_k=b_k+r_b $
   $z_k=c_k+r_c $
3. $F(x,y,z)$ – This function is used as a constraint in the algorithm to ensure that the calculated values of $r_a$, $r_b$, and $r_c$ satisfy the given measurements.
   $F\left(x,y,z\right)=3x^2y^2+3x^2z^2+3y^2z^2+6x^2yz+6{xy}^2z+6xyz^2-\frac{\left(x^2+y^2+xy\right)\left(x^2+z^2+xz\right)\left(y^2+z^2+yz\right)}{R^2}$
4. The partial derivatives of $F\left(x,y,z\right)\ - F_x\left(x,y,z\right)$, $F_y\left(x,y,z\right)$, $F_z\left(x,y,z\right)$ with respect to $x,\ y,\ z$.
   The partial derivatives are an essential to optimization process as they directly affect magnitude and direction that $r_a$ , $r_b$, and $r_c$ is incremented with each iteration ${(dr}_a{,dr}_b{,dr}_c)$.
   $F_x(x,y,z) = 6xy^2+ 6xz^2+ 12xyz + 6y^2 z + 6yz^2 - \frac{(2x + y)(x^2+ z^2+ xz)(y^2+ z^2+ yz)}{R^2} -\frac{(x^2+ y^2+ xy)(2x + z)(y^2+ z^2+ yz)}{R^2} $
   $F_y\left(x,y,z\right)=F_x\left(x,y,z\right) $
   $F_z\left(x,y,z\right)=F_x\left(x,y,z\right) $
   (Due to the symmetry of $F(x,y,z)$)
5. An system of linear equations for the increments ${(dr}_a{,dr}_b{,dr}_c)$.
   These equations represent the conditions that need to be satisfied for the increments ${(dr}_a{,dr}_b{,dr}_c)$ to ensure that the changes in the function $F\left(x,y,z\right)$ with respect to each variable are zero at the specific point ${(x}_k{,y}_k{,z}_k)$.
   $F_x\left(x_k,y_k,z_k\right)dr_a{+F}_y\left(x_k,y_k,z_k\right)dr_b+F_z\left(x_k,y_k,z_k\right)dr_c=-F(x_k,y_k,z_k)$
   The left-hand side of this equation represents change in $F$ at the point ${(x}_K{,y}_K{,z}_K)$ caused by the increments ${(dr}_a{,dr}_b{,dr}_c)$, while the right-hand side is the negative value of $F$ at that point. By setting them equal to each other, you are essentially trying to make the net change in $F$ equal to zero. This equation ensures that the increments ${(dr}_a{,dr}_b{,dr}_c)$ are chosen in a way that counteracts the change in $F$ caused by variations in $(x, y, z)$ and moves the solution towards the desired minimum or maximum of $F$ with each iteration.
   $\frac{f(x_K,y_K,z_K)}{R}\ dr_a=0 $
   $\frac{f(x_K,y_K,z_K)}{R}\ dr_b=0 $
   $\frac{f(x_K,y_K,z_K)}{R}\ dr_c=0 $
   These equations represent additional constraints on the increments ${(dr}_a{,dr}_b{,dr}_c)$.
   These equations ensure that the increments ${dr}_a{,dr}_b$ and ${dr}_c$  are constrained in a way that aligns with the behaviour of the function $F(x_K,y_K,z_K)$ and its relationship with $R$. By satisfying these conditions, the algorithm can find solutions that minimize the error and converge towards the desired result.

With the required functions established lets define the steps of the iterative method.
**The following steps will be executed:**

1. Initialize the values of $r_a$ , $r_b$, and $r_c$ to some initial guess, such as $R/2$.
2. Construct the matrices $U$ and $V$ by evaluating the partial derivatives and function values for each measurement point $k$.
3. Solve the system of linear equations to obtain the increments $V$
   $V\ =\left(U^TU\right)^{-1}U^TV$
4. Update $r_a$ , $r_b$, and $r_c$ by adding the corresponding elements of $V$ to the previous values.
5. Check if any of the updated values of $r_a$, $r_b$, or $r_c$ are negative. If so, revert them back to their previous values.
6. Calculate the mean quadratic error $G$ based on the updated values of $r_a$, $r_b$, and $r_c$
7. Compare the new mean quadratic error $G$ with the previous minimum error $e$ If it is lower, update $e$ and store the values of $r_a$, $r_b$ and $r_c$ as the new suspected minimizer.
8. Repeat steps 2-7 until the termination condition is met (e.g., when $e$ is within the desired tolerance or after a maximum number of iterations).

We can now implement these steps. (Implemented in Asymptote):

```
//Measurements from CAD
real[] a = {5.2491254, 3.5261623, 5.2425714, 5.6053228, 2.6211544, 5.6305936, 3.1218340, 2.8136425, 6.7312779, 3.7744161};
real[] b = {3.6421203, 4.0069957, 2.2366199, 4.0762025, 4.3330685, 1.7881182, 5.3989306, 3.7336225, 1.6301678, 5.6724511};
real[] c = {5.5479800, 6.9097135, 6.9231890, 4.5958384, 7.3330685, 6.8966301, 5.7511286, 7.7652347, 5.7985227, 4.7375570};

//Masterpart radius
real R = 12.5;

//Number of measurements
int K = a.length;

//Define the mean quadratic error G
real G(real ra, real rb, real rc, real[] a, real[] b, real[] c)
{
  real s = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
  {
    real x = ra + a[k];
    real y = rb + b[k];
    real z = rc + c[k];
    real error = sqrt(((x^2 + y^2 + x * y) * (x^2 + z^2 + x * z) * (y^2 + z^2 + y * z)) / (3 * x^2 * y^2 + 3 * x^2 * z^2 + 3 * y^2 * z^2 + 6 * x^2 * y * z + 6 * x * y^2 * z + 6 * x * y * z^2)) - R;
    s += abs(error)^2;
  }
  return sqrt(s / K);
}

//Define the main function F
real f(real x, real y, real z)
{
  return 3 * x^2 * y^2 + 3 * x^2 * z^2 + 3 * y^2 * z^2 + 6 * x^2 * y * z + 6 * x * y^2 * z + 6 * x * y * z^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + x * y) * (x^2 + z^2 + x * z) * (y^2 + z^2 + y * z) / R^2;
}

//Define the partial derivatives
real Fx(real x, real y, real z)
{
  return 6 * x * y^2 + 6 * x * z^2 + 12 * x * y * z + 6 * y^2 * z + 6 * y * z^2 - (2 * x + y) * (x^2 + z^2 + x * z) * (y^2 + z^2 + y * z) / R^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + x * y) * (2 * x + z) * (y^2 + z^2 + y * z) / R^2;
}

real Fy(real x, real y, real z)
{
  return Fx(y, x, z);
}

real Fz(real x, real y, real z)
{
  return Fx(z, x, y);
}

// Initialize variables
real e = G(R / 2, R / 2, R / 2, a, b, c);
real ra = R / 2;
real rb = R / 2;
real rc = R / 2;

int maxIterations = 50;
real tolerance = 0.0001; // Tolerance for termination condition
int iteration = 0;

// Perform the iterations
while (iteration < maxIterations && e > tolerance)
{
  iteration = iteration + 1;

  // Construct the matrices U and V
  real[][] U, V;
  for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
  {
    real x = ra + a[k];
    real y = rb + b[k];
    real z = rc + c[k];

    U[k] = new real[] {Fx(x, y, z), Fy(x, y, z), Fz(x, y, z)};
    V[k] = new real[] {-f(x, y, z)};
    U[k + K] = new real[] {abs(f(x, y, z)) / R, 0, 0};
    V[k + K] = new real[] {0};
    U[k + 2 * K] = new real[] {0, abs(f(x, y, z)) / R, 0};
    V[k + 2 * K] = new real[] {0};
    U[k + 3 * K] = new real[] {0, 0, abs(f(x, y, z)) / R};
    V[k + 3 * K] = new real[] {0};
  }

  // Calculate the least squares solution
  V = inverse(transpose(U) * U) * transpose(U) * V;

  real rra = ra;
  real rrb = rb;
  real rrc = rc;

  // Update ra, rb, rc
  ra += V[0][0];
  rb += V[1][0];
  rc += V[2][0];

  // Check for negative values and update if necessary
  if (ra < 0) ra = rra;
  if (rb < 0) rb = rrb;
  if (rc < 0) rc = rrc;

  // Update the minimum value if the new error is lower
  if (G(ra, rb, rc, a, b, c) < e && ra > 0 && rb > 0 && rc > 0)
  {
    e = G(ra, rb, rc, a, b, c);
  }
}

  write("iterations completed= ",iteration);
  write("ra = ", ra);
  write("rb = ", rb);
  write("rc = ", rc);
  write("error = ", e);
```

**Results:**
After executing the script we get the following results:
[image]
We found the solution in only 6 iterations and the mean error of the calculated radius is $1.647\times10^{-8}$ mm.

Comment: It's possible that your CAD software can do it for you using equality constraints and whatnot.

Comment: There is a quick approximate technique that requires solving a 4 by 4 linear system and works reasonably well when the bung is not too much smaller than the master ring (so the distance between their centers is a reasonably small portion of the diameter). On your data it outputs 8.017,  8.995, 5.991 for $r_a,r_b,r_c$ respectively. Even if this precision is unsatisfactory by itself, you can then, probably, run Newton's method on Joshua's equations starting with this approximate solution. Would you be interested in seeing it?

Comment: Try with `FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {ra, 0}, {rb, 0}, {rc, 0}]`. And set `Diameter=25`, which is missing in your code.

Comment: @Msegling OK, after a couple of days of experimenting with various approaches, I can post a long answer that you might find rather interesting, but my previous experience with some people was that they disappeared from the site before I could really say anything and never came back, so, please respond to this comment if you want me to share my 2 cents :-) Otherwise  I'll just switch to something else...

Comment: @fedja I am fully committed. Many engineers have had this exact challenge. Finding a mathematical solution would greatly benefit the community. I have not yet reached a complete resolution to this problem. The Findroots function is not accessible to me as I need to program this solution in SCL. A step-by-step explanation would be immensely valuable to me in order to independently implement the solution. At present, I am actively experimenting with the Broyden method, and once I have successfully derived the solution on paper, my goal is to translate it into code. Looking forward to your post.

Comment: @fedja Please ensure that you are using the updated datapoints (a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3). The previous datapoints, which were rounded to three decimal places, which may have introduced errors in the calculations.

Comment: If you have more than 3 sets of measurements, performing least-squares optimization using the calculated vs. known inner diameters may work.

Comment: Hi, Msegling! I presume you are just too busy at work or with some other stuff to continue the discussion today. I'll be happy to wait as long as you need, but I really want some feedback on what I said already to see where we stand and what we agree and disagree upon and which points I've made so far are clear and which are obscure. So, I'll wait for your response before continuing beyond what I posted yesterday. And please, accept my apologies if anything I said was offensive or too obnoxious in any way. I just wanted to show you my thinking process :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, time to start typing. As I said, it is a long story, so I'll have to post in parts. I'll start with clearly stating what (IMHO) are the main objectives here. One has to design an algorithm/theory that, given the (possibly somewhat erratic) set of measurements $a_k,b_k,c_k$ for $k=1,\dots,K$ of the muster part of the known radius $R$ (I prefer to deal with the radius rather than with the diameter),

a) produces the values of $r_a, r_b, r_c$ that allow to explain all the given data within the measurement error whatever that error is (it may be unknown)

b) allows to predict with reasonable certainty what will be the device calibration error compared to the standard measurement error in the data, so one could just by looking at the data tell whether the calibration with these data will be successful or you'd better take new (additional) measurements before computing.

c) is easy to communicate as a set of simple formulas, recipes, and code pieces even if the derivations are omitted.

So, what I did was to write a test program that generates random data and couple it with a universal algorithm that would try to find the solutions for that data and then compares those solutions with the truth. It took me about 5 days to find the universal algorithm that works on every reasonable (again, IMHO) data set, so I designed something that satisfied me completely only this morning. Please, accept my apologies for the delay.

You are, probably, most eager to see the algorithm first. Warning: you'll need to code yourself to implement it and to play with it, so forget all about CAS and "solve()" or "findroot()" commands. We'll do things from scratch in the old-fashioned way.

***The algorithm***

Following Joshua's formula, define the functions

```
real num(real x, real y, real z)
{
return (x^2+y^2+x*y)*(x^2+z^2+x*z)*(y^2+z^2+y*z);
}

real den(real x, real y, real z)
{
return 3*x^2*y^2+3*x^2*z^2+3*y^2*z^2+6*x^2*y*z+6*x*y^2*z+6*x*y*z^2;
}

real F(real x, real y, real z)
{
return
3*x^2*y^2+3*x^2*z^2+3*y^2*z^2+6*x^2*y*z+6*x*y^2*z+6*x*y*z^2
-(x^2+y^2+x*y)*(x^2+z^2+x*z)*(y^2+z^2+y*z)/R^2;
}

real RAD(real x, real y, real z)
{
return sqrt(num(x,y,z)/den(x,y,z));
}



real G(real ra, real rb, real rc)
{
real s=0;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
real x=ra+a[k], y=rb+b[k], z=rc+c[k];
s+=abs(sqrt(num(x,y,z)/den(x,y,z))-R)^2; 
}
return sqrt(s/K);
}
```

(the language is Asymptote; if you know C or something similar, it should be reasonably easy to follow). num(), den(), F() should be clear, RAD() is the formula for R in Jeshua's variables and G() computes the mean quadratic error of the equations for $R$ given the guess $r_a,r_b,r_c$.

We shall also need the partial derivatives

```
real Fx(real x, real y, real z)
{
return
6*x*y^2+6*x*z^2+12*x*y*z+6*y^2*z+6*y*z^2
-(2*x+y)*(x^2+z^2+x*z)*(y^2+z^2+y*z)/R^2
-(x^2+y^2+x*y)*(2*x+z)*(y^2+z^2+y*z)/R^2;
}

real Fy(real x, real y, real z)
{return Fx(y,x,z);}

real Fz(real x, real y, real z)
{return Fx(z,x,y);}
```

(I used the symmetry of $F$ to avoid retyping the long expressions). Now our task is just to minimize $G$. We will run 50 tries and choose the best result.

Let us store the best achieved guess and the corresponding value somewhere and initialize it to something:

```
real mnm=G(R/2,R/2,R/2), raa=R/2,rbb=R/2,rcc=R/2;
```

On each try, we may take the initial guess at random in the cube $[0,2R]^3$, i.e., write

```
real ra,rb,rc;
ra=2*R*unitrand(); rb=2*R*unitrand();rc=2*R*unitrand();
```

There *is* a better choice but to discuss it now would be quite a digression, so I'll postpone it until later.

Now we do the following iteration 50 times.

We set up an overdetermined system of linear equations for the increments $dr_a, dr_b, dr_c$ with 4 equations for each $k$ (so we'll have $4K$ equations with $3$ unknowns).

For each $k$, we compute the corresponding $x_k=r_a+a_k, y_k=r_b+b_k, z_k=r_c+c_k$ and set the 4 equations
$$
F_x(x_k,y_k,z_k) dr_a+F_y(x_k,y_k,z_k) dr_b+
F_z(x_k,y_k,z_k) dr_c=-F(x_k,y_k,z_k)
\\
(F(x_k,y_k,z_k)/R) dr_a=0
\\
(F(x_k,y_k,z_k)/R) dr_b=0
\\
(F(x_k,y_k,z_k)/R) dr_c=0
$$
Then we find the least square solution $dr_a, dr_b, dr_c$ of this overdetermined system and replace
$r_a,r_b,r_c$ by $r_a+dr_a, r_b+dr_b, r_c+dr_c$ except that if some replacement results in a negative value, we just don't do it. Now compute $G$ of the new set and if it is better that the minimum observed so far, update the suspected minimizer and the minimal value.

The corresponding piece of code is below (Asymprote allows one an easy handling of matrix algebra, so I chose it for this reason plus we'll need its graphing capabilities to discuss analytics).

```
for(int m=0;m<50;++m)
{
real[][] U,V;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
real x=ra+a[k], y=rb+b[k], z=rc+c[k];
U[k]=new real[]{Fx(x,y,z), Fy(x,y,z), Fz(x,y,z)}; V[k]=new real[]{-F(x,y,z)};
}
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
real x=ra+a[k], y=rb+b[k], z=rc+c[k];
U[k+K]=new real[]{abs(F(x,y,z)/R), 0, 0}; V[k+K]=new real[]{0};
}
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
real x=ra+a[k], y=rb+b[k], z=rc+c[k];
U[k+2*K]=new real[]{0, abs(F(x,y,z)/R), 0}; V[k+2*K]=new real[]{0};
}
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
real x=ra+a[k], y=rb+b[k], z=rc+c[k];
U[k+3*K]=new real[]{0, 0, abs(F(x,y,z)/R)}; V[k+3*K]=new real[]{0};
}

V=inverse(transpose(U)*U)*transpose(U)*V;

real rra=ra,rrb=rb,rrc=rc;

ra+=V[0][0];
rb+=V[1][0];
rc+=V[2][0];

if(ra<0) ra=rra;
if(rb<0) rb=rrb;
if(rc<0) rc=rrc;

if(G(ra,rb,rc)<mnm && ra>0 && rb>0 && rc>0) {mnm=G(ra,rb,rc); raa=ra; rbb=rb; rcc=rc;};
```

Remember that one needs to run this piece 50 times (in my simulations the largest necessary number to reach the precision of the true data was 16, but let's give it the standard engineering 3-fold margin).

That's the full "universal algorithm". What I claim is that for reasonably diverse measurements (we'll discuss what it means below), it will achieve the full explanations of the given measurements. However, a full explanation is not yet the truth and it is its predictive value we are after. But that calls for a separate discussion that I'll post later. For now, I'll just say that my simulations show that just $K=3$ is seldom sufficient (to the extent that multiple exact solutions are possible), so one needs at least 4 calibration measurements and, based on the error analysis, I would really strongly recommend 8 to 10, though one can often get away with 5 to 7.

***The stability analysis***

Now it is time to discuss the second question. Before I go into it, I'd like to make two  important general points about experimental science in general:

1. There is no way to derive the truth from observations. All we can possibly hope for is an explanation of the observed data/phenomena that agrees with all observations within an observation error.
2. We do not need the truth. All that we really need is an explanation with high predictive power.

Note that there may be an explanation that agrees with all  available observations  but is still very poor when it comes to making predictions. A lot of such explanations were  developed using very sophisticated mathematical models for explaining the COVID dinamics and most modern and ancient ideolodical ideas  seem to fall into the  same category. I'll abstain from going into the general discussion of what it might mean for the world we live in here but we need to understand clearly what it means for our problem nevertheless.

The truth for us is the actual triple $(R_a, R_b, R_c)$. Suppose that the typical error measurement of $(a,b,c)$ in your device is of size $\varepsilon$. Then the first principle tells you that when testing a solver, you cannot and shouldn't judge the performance of any solver by the actual difference between the values $r_a,r_b,r_c$ it outputs and the corresponding $R's$, i.e. by the quantity $|Ra-r_a|+|R_b-r_b|+|R_c-r_c|$ or something similar. All you can and should judge it by  is the set of the differences $|RAD(r_a+a_k,r_b+b_k,r_c+c_k)-R|$ on your data $(a_k,b_k,c_k)$ and if all these values  (almost) always do not exceed $\varepsilon$, you will have to declare  that the solver did a  good job no matter how far the actual values it output are far from the truth. Indeed, all the measurements have been explained within the measurement error, so there is no way one can disprove from these observations alone that the output *is* the truth.  In this respect the solver I proposed is nearly perfect and becomes even more perfect with a few extra twists.

The second principle means that we do not actually care how much we deviate from the truth $(R_a,R_b,R_c)$. All we care about is the predictive power of our explanation, i.e., the maximum of  possible differences $|RAD(r_a+a,r_b+b,r_c+c)-RAD(R_a+a,R_b+b,R_c+c)|$ over all plausible future measurements $(a,b,c)$. If that is of order $\varepsilon$ too, then we should be completely happy even if our deviation from the truth is much larger than $\varepsilon$ itself.

One should also understand that some sets of observed measurements are better than other. For instance, if we have the set in which all measurements were taken from essentially the same position, they would be easy to explain together but the predictive power of such explanation will be most likely pretty low for other positions. In particular, if you do the measurements from the concentric positions of the measuring tool and the master ring, you'll just have one set of $a,b,c$ no matter how you rotate and it can be easily explained by many off-center positions as well. So one obvious practical advice is that if you have any control over placing your measuring tool when calibrating at all, you should aim for placing it as far from the center of the master ring as you possibly can. We'll see below that when using the calibrating tool  for measurement of unknown radii, you should do exactly the opposite and place it as close to the concentric position as you can, if you can control it at all.

Now let us do the formal analysis keeping these points in mind.

The true Joshua's system of equations is not algebraicly solvable, so we will have to approximate the equations to carry out our analysis. Assuming that we are not too far from the concentric position, we can just try to approximate the equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ by  its second order Taylor expansion near the point $x=y=z=R$. Note that normally the stability analysis is carried out by just using the linear approximation but our issue is that the function is symmetric, so its linear part at the diagonal must be symmetric as well and, thereby, is just proportional to $(x-R)+(y-R)+(z-R)$, so the differentiial is very degenerate and the stability of the solution, if it is there at all, must come from the quadratic or higher order terms.''

The second order approximation of the equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ is
$$
\frac{(x-R)+(y-R)+(z-R)}3+\frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{18R}=0;
$$
The second term actually has a geometric meaning: it is approximately $\frac{\lambda^2}{4R}$ where $\lambda$ is the distance between the centers of the measuring tool and the master ring. I'll skip the derivations for now (but can provide them upon request)

Plugging in $x=r_a+a, y=r_b+b, z=r_c+c$ and putting  all the known quantities of the right, we get the equation
$$
\left[\frac{r_a+r_b+r_c}3+\frac{(r_a-r_b)^2+((r_b-r_c)^2+(r_c-r_a)^2)}{18R}\right]
\\
+\frac{a-b}{9R}(r_a-r_b)+\frac{b-c}{9R}(r_b-r_c)+\frac{c-a}{9R}(r_c-r_a)=
\\
R-\frac{a+b+c}3-\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}{18R}
$$
We have $K$ such equations for $a=a_k, b=b_k, c=c_k$. Note that unlike the original system coming from $F(x,y,z)=0$, this new system is explicitly solvable: if we denote the quantity in the brackets by $U$ and introduce $r_{ab}=r_a-r_b$, etc., the LHS will be just
$$
U+\frac{a-b}{9R}r_{ab}+\frac{b-c}{9R} r_{bc}+\frac{c-a}{9R}r_{ca}\,.
$$
Adding to this system the obvious equation $r_{ab}+r_{bc}+r_{ca}=0$, we get a *linear* system with four unknowns $U,r_{ab}, r_{bc}, r_{ca}$, which can be readily solved by the least square method even if it is overdetermined. Once we know these 4 variables, it is easy to recover the sum $r_a+r_b+r_c$ from $U$ and then $r_a,r_b,r_c$ themselves.

The stability of the solution to this system with respect to the perturbations of $a_k$, $b_k$, $c_k$ can be readily analyzed and one can hope that the stability properties of the actual system near the true solution are not too different. Let $A$ be the matrix of the system with $K$ rows $1, \frac{a_k-b_k}{9R},\frac{b_k-c_k}{9R},\frac{c_k-a_k}{9R}$ and one row $10,1,1,1$ for the last trivial equation (actually, since it should hold exactly, for the least square method one should rather put some big constant instead of $1$ into the last row). Let also $B$ be the column given by the RHS of the above system augmented by $0$ in the bottom position. The whole system then just becomes $AS=B$ where $S$ is the column with our $4$ unknowns and the least square solution becomes $S=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$ and it minimizes the norm $\|AS-B\|$. Note that from the latter fact it is easy to see that the $r_{ab},r_{bc},r_{ca}$ part of the solution remains the same if we subtract from $B$ any multiple of the column with $K$ ones and $1$ zero because this subtraction can be perfectly compensated by changing the value of $U$. Thus, to analyze the change in the pairwise differences, we can use the RHS $B'$ instead of $B$, where $B'$ is obtained from $B$ by subtracting the average value of its first $K$ entries from each of them, which makes the norm of $B'$ as small as it can be.

Note that introducing the errors into $a_k, b_k,c_k$ changes *both* $A$ and $B$. Let $E$ be the change in the matrix $A$ and $e$ be the change in the vector $B$. These hanges are with entries of order $\varepsilon/R$ and $\varepsilon$ respectively  where $\varepsilon$ is the measurement error of the device.

Now, linearizing, we see that the change in the pairwide difference part of $S$ is about
$$
-(A^TA)^{-1}(E^TA+A^TE)(A^TA)^{-1}B'+(A^TA)^{-1}A^Te
$$
Thus the relevant quantities are
$$
C_1=\|(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\| \text{ and }C_2=C_1^2\|B'\|/R
$$
giving the typical error in the pairwise differences of order $\varepsilon \sqrt(C^2+C_1^2)=C\varepsilon$ (ignoring the absolute numeric coefficients that can be easily derived analytically or just discerned from the simulations).

The quantity $C_1$ can be also expressed as $\sqrt{(\|A^TA)^{-1}\|}$, which has the advantage of  being a norm of a $4\times 4$ symmetric matrix, so its rough computation is trivial. Thus, the constant $C$ can be easily determined and, most importantly, its determination can be made from the observed data alone. It essentially measures the deviation from the truth. The error in the sum $r_a+r_b+r_c$ is smaller and, unless we have a really pathological scenario, is determined by the linear approximation, which is robust and doesn't depend on the possible singularity of $A$ too much (I'll produce some graphs and diagrams later to show what I mean). But we remember that we should never be interested in the truth itself (unless we want to get engaged into meaningless arguments and gruel pointless fights, which seem to go all over the planet all the time, presumably in the name of that very truth), only in the predictive power of our explanations. So our next task will be to convert the estimate of the deviation from the truth we derived into the estimate of the predictive power of our calibration. We will see something interesting there too, but not today.

***The predictive power  (the evaluation of the quality of the calibration from the data)"**

Apologies for the phylosophical digression, but I found it necessary to explain what we should be after here. I noticed that you were amazed that Mathematica could find a solution from just 3 observations (and, most likely, with machine precision regardless of the measurement errors). That is not really something to be excited about.  First , my homeemade contraption is perfectly capable of this too. And second, more importantly, what you really want it to do based on the data you feed in is to give you an explicit bound on the predictive power of its explanation, i.e., to tell you what error you should expect in the real future measurements after your calibration is done and what is the actual (not declared) accuracy of the measuring tool. Note that 3 observations will never allow you to answer even the latter question because the system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns has an exact solution more often than not. So you would like to increase the number of observations just for this purpose, if nothing else. Now we are going to address the more interesting first question.

The underlying idea is simple. We will deal with the same approximation as above
$$
R\approx \frac{x+y+z}3+\frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{18R}
$$
Ignoring for the moment that $R$ on the RHS is also unknown, we can say that the calibration error will influence this formula by first the error in the average, which will be the error in $r_a+r_b+r_c$ and second by the error in the quadratic term, which will be the scalar product of the vector $(x-y,y-z,z-x)$ and the deviation from the truth in the vector $(r_{ab},r_{bc},r_{ca})$. We have already estimated the norm of the latter vector by $C\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is the actual accuracy of the machine (I do not presume it known) and $C$ is the above constant that we can compute from the data alone. The norm of the first vector is essentially the deviation $\lambda$ of the center of the measuring tool from the center of the master ring, so, bringing all that stuff together, we see that the expected error  in the second term is proportional with some numeric coefficient to $C\Lambda \varepsilon$ where $\Lambda=\lambda/R$ is the relative (to the radius of the master ring) deviation from the center. For the first term, we may expect that its error is about the same as if the approximation were just linear, in which case we can invoke the independence of errors and additivity of variance to conclude that it should be of order $\frac 1{\sqrt K}$. There is also a question of numeric coefficients, but they depend on what exactly we are going to estimate, so let us discuss that now. Note at any rate that the big error in the pairwise difference vector (compared to $\varepsilon$) can be compensated by small $\Lambda$. So, if you intend to measure just the rings slightly exceeding the measuring tool itself, you shouldn't be afraid of it too much. The measurement will come out nearly correct despite $r_a, r_b, r_c$ will be rather wrong individually. However, nothing can compensate the error in the sum.

What I did for testing was to take the (simulated) calibrated tool, was to place it at given $\Lambda$ into a random larger ring of comparable radius and take the maximal error in the determination of that radius over all rotations in that fixed position (i.e., for every rotation I computed true $a,b,c$ from $R_a,R_b,R_c$ and hten used these values to evaluate the radius from them and calibration values $r_a,r_b,r_c$. Let's call this maximal error $E(\Lambda)$ (technically it also depends on the radius, but funnily enough, this dependence is nearly zero). My predictor $P(\Lambda)$ for this error will be just a weighted sum of $\frac 1{sqrt K}$ and $C\Lambda$ times $\varepsilon$. The  sweet coefficients (assuming I want $P$ to be an almost guaranteed upper bound) are
$$
P(\lambda)=[\sqrt{\frac 4{3K}}+\frac C4\Lambda]\varepsilon\,.
$$

It remains to run a few thousand simulations varying the calibration setups to see if the predictor is efficient. What I did was to create a few dot diagrams plotting the points $E(\Lambda)/P(\lambda),P(\Lambda)/\varepsilon$ choosing the same amount of points (500) for each interval between two integers for the value of  $P$ (technically I just ran completely random calibrations and placed the results on the dot diagram until intervals got saturated; note that in the dot diagram it is important to have the same number of points for each interval for the value of the predictor to make the distributions easy to compare). Below are such diagrams for several values of $K$ (the value of $P$ is vertical in the range from $0$ to $50$ and $E$ is horizontal).  The green line on the left shows which intervals are, indeed, saturated after 20000 runs, so you can compare the corresponding boxed visually. The grid is $1$ by $1$. In addition to each dot dyagram, I I drew the hystogram of $E(\Lambda)/P(\lambda)$ for $5<P(\Lambda)<6$. Here is a typical pair of diagrams for $K=4$:

[image]
[image]

You can see that, indeed, there are a lot of points to the left of $1$ ($E=P$) but not too many to the right of it for *every* value of $P$ for which we got the required number of points in the corresponding horizontal box at all, which means that our predictor has some reasonable predicting power.

Of course, the good calibration is a calibration with reasonably low $C$, so that the calibrating error does not exceed the true measuring tool error, i.e., the machine is calibrated to its capability. Note that agreeing the values on the observations within the required precision is not enough. If $C$ is large, the calibration will still be most likely erratic and you'll not be able to use the tool unless $\Lambda$ is guaranteed to be small. Note also that $C$ is computable from the data alone, so you can decide whether your results are satisfactory or not. For the decision including the whole range of $\Lambda$ up to $0$, we will also need a predictor of the error in the sum, but let's play with this simple one-parameter predictor first.

The value of $C$ is determined by the luck and the typical relative distance to the center $\Lambda_c$ during the calibration. The general rule is that $C$ is inversely proportional to $\Lambda_c$ and also diminishes with $K$ like $1/\sqrt K$, but also its distribution (assuming $K$ random measurements with typical relative deviation from the center $\Lambda_c$ ) gets more concentrated with $K$.

Here are the distributions of $C\Lambda_c\sqrt(K)/4$ for $K=4$ and $K=12$ and $\Lambda_c=0.05$ and $\Lambda_c=0.5$ (truncated at 6). Can you guess which is which?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

***An intermission"**

Before going into the next topic, I'd like to do two things. The first one is to give you one more piece of code. You can just copy the whole module to an asy file (my file name for it is aboreappsolve.asy, so if you want us to easily share some code modules without renaming in the Asymptote import commands, I suggest you use the same name when saving the file).

This module just solves the approximate system we have discussed above and produces a few parameters that will be needed for constructing the final error predictor. The approximate solution is the .sol field of the AS (Almost Solution) structure. You can (and, IMHO, should) also try to use it as the initial approximation in the main solver algorithm as the first try. Just write

triple T=APPSOLVE(a,b,c,R).sol;
ra=T.x; rb=T.y, rc=T.c;

in the main code. (and import aboreappsolve; in the beginning of it, of course).

In the vast majority of cases, it is good enough to finish the story off in 4-10 iterations on the very first try after that *but not always*, so do not discard the random tries entirely yet.  BTW, I found it more convenient and making more sense for the testing to stop the iteration loop in a single try  not when the required accuracy is reached but just when it stops moving, i.e., when the increments are comparable to the machine precision. But we'll discuss the testing techniques later.

The $C$ we were talking about is the .sig field of the AS structure. The other two fields real[] Aa and real[][] A are going to be used to get a refined predictor for the error in the sum $r_a+r_b+r_c$. That is really interesting only if we want to deal with really small $\Lambda$  after the calibration with decent value of $C$. Otherwise the $C$-term normally dominates that extra correction anyway.

The second thing I want is to get some feedback from you onwhat I have said already. If everything is clear, just say "All clear". But if you feel lost or overwhelmed already, trying to push more mathematics and programming down your throat before the previous parts are fully digested will be just a waste of time for both of us. So, please react! I hate talking into the empty space. I wish we were sitting in the same room for this discussion, but, unless you would be excited to make a trip to the middle of nowhere in rural Ohio, this is, probably, not an option.

Now, the code module, as promised:

aboreappsolve.asy

```
import three;
struct AS {triple sol; real sig; real[][] A; real[] Aa;};

AS APPSOLVE(real[] a, real[] b, real[] c, real R)
{

int K=a.length;

real ra,rb,rc;

real[][] A,B,Q,AA;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
A[k]=new real[]{(a[k]-b[k])/9/R, (b[k]-c[k])/9/R, (c[k]-a[k])/9/R, 1};
B[k]=new real[]{R-(a[k]+b[k]+c[k])/3-((a[k]-b[k])^2+(b[k]-c[k])^2+(c[k]-a[k])^2)/18/R};
}

A[K]=new real[]{20*K,20*K,20*K,0};
B[K]=new real[]{0};

real bb=0;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k) bb+=B[k][0]/K;
real b2=0;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k) b2+=(B[k][0]-bb)^2;
b2=sqrt(b2);

Q=inverse(transpose(A)*A)*transpose(A)*B;
AA=inverse(transpose(A)*A);
AA*=AA; AA*=AA; AA*=AA;

real cond=(AA[0][0]+AA[1][1]+AA[2][2])^(1/16), cond1=cond^2/R*b2;


real[] Aa={0,0,0,0};
for(int k=0;k<K;++k) Aa+=A[k]/K;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k) A[k]-=Aa;
A[K+1]=new real[] {0,0,0,20*K};

A*=9; Aa*=9;

AA=inverse(transpose(A)*A);

AS T=new AS;

T.sig=sqrt(cond^2+cond1^2);
T.A=AA;
T.Aa=new real[]{Aa[0],Aa[1],Aa[2]};

real av=Q[3][0]-(Q[0][0]^2+Q[1][0]^2+Q[2][0]^2)/18/R;
ra=max(av+(Q[0][0]-Q[2][0])/3,0);
rb=max(av+(Q[1][0]-Q[0][0])/3,0); rc=max(av+(Q[2][0]-Q[1][0])/3,0);

if(ra==0 && rb==0 && rc==0) {ra=R/2; rb=R/2; rc=R/2;}

T.sol=(ra,rb,rc);

return T;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive explanation! The prospect of assessing the need for more calibration data upfront is indeed exciting. Obtaining 10 measurements should not present any significant challenges, especially considering that recalibration would typically be necessary when the probes have been adjusted. I will proceed to download Asymptote to further explore and experiment with the algorithm you have presented.

Comment: I have implemented your solution in Asymptote and updated to the original question accordingly. Your solution is is nothing short of excellent. I have added a stopping condition to terminate the algorithm once the required accuracy is reached. I am extremely satisfied with the results achieved using your solution. Furthermore, I have conducted a brief study comparing the number of measurements (K) to the error (G). It is my expectation that in real-world scenarios, the impact of measurement diversity will be even more pronounced. I am excited to further improve on this solution.

Comment: @Msegling I posted the second morsel. There will be a few more but I'm a slow typist and my free time is limited, so, please, be patient with me. Feel free to ask as many questions as you need if something is unclear.

Comment: @Msegling I added more stuff that you may find interesting. Let me know what you think. There is more to say yet :-)

Comment: Thank you for providing me with such insightful information! I am taking the time to thoroughly comprehend every aspect of your second morsel. I am in the process of updating the original question based on the knowledge I have gained from your genius solutions! I aim to provide an update sometime this weekend, presenting a synthesis of your expertise along with my own perspective as a learner. I want to ensure that my understanding is accurate, and I would greatly appreciate it if you could correct any misunderstandings I may have.

Comment: The importance of predictive power, as opposed to an exclusive focus on the notion of "truth," has resonated with me. Im considering using this argument next time in a debate with a theist. Ohio is a long way from where I stay... thats an understatement. As for your next update... give me some time to properly digest this first. If there is anything im unsure of i'll mention it with my next update... or you may pickup that i misunderstood. Thank you for helping me navigate this fascinating subject!

Comment: @Msegling Thanks for your quick response! OK, take your time and we'll continue on the weekend or after it. For the graphs and constants, I should mention that my model is that every measurement of, say, $a$ has an independent error uniformly distributed on the interval $[\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ and that the measurements are done from independent positions within a disk near the center of radius $\Lambda_c R$. I think it makes sense for this type of machinery, but if you believe that the Gaussian model of the error is better, we'll just recompute the constants.

Comment: @Msegling The main points that I'm trying to make now are that the calibration that merely explains all the existing data up to the measuring tool precision may be still both good and terrible depending on the stability of the found solution under small perturbations of the data and that it is both possible and highly desirable to determine with high probability which one is the actual case just by looking at the measurements provided for the calibration alone.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you, and I appreciate your patience. I have been reviewing your second morsel and im almost done with formulating what I've learned. I wanted to address the question you raised regarding the best model for the application. Generally I default to a Gaussian model but to be completely honest I do not have a definitive answer. Luckily I will have a definitive answer once the machine is assembled and we have access to the data. If you are still interested then I would love to share the raw data with you then. (It may be a month or two from now)...

Comment: ... moving on, I would like to clarify a specific aspect related to the simulation you mentioned when determing E(Λ). I would just like to inform you that the tool itself should be restricted to not be able to physically rotate and it will be placed automatically. There may be micro-roations but nothing major. I apologize for not mentioning that earlier. However Im assuming that by rotating the tool, you are effectively simulating the effect of placing the tool in different positions. Thinking about it now... its probably equivalent to new placement in the x/y position.

Comment: ... finally I want to query the formula for the predictor function P(λ). In the formula P(λ) = [√(4/3λ) + C/4Λ]ε that you provided, I noticed the absence of the term 1/√K, which represents the contribution of 1/√K in the error estimation. I would appreciate it if you could shed some light on the rationale behind its omission. I am curious to understand whether this exclusion was intentional, an oversight, or perhaps a simplification made for the purposes of the analysis.

Comment: @Msegling Probably, there were a few misprints (about $\sqrt K$), I'll try to address them tomorrow in the morning. Meanwhile I am posting a more precise estimation now based on the actual equation system instead of the approximate one, which gives you higher accuracy. Try to use this one instead for evaluation purposes. The Asymptote code is provided.

Comment: @Msegling Yep, absence of $\sqrt K$ was a misprint. I just typed $\lambda$ instead of $K$ (don't ask me why :-) ). I corrected it so I hope it makes more sense now. Anyway, I added a more accurate diagnostics. Unfortunately, I had to start a new answer: the system told me that I was exceeding the character limit when I tried to edit the old one...

Comment: @Msegling And it looks to me that moving around preserving the distance to the center without rotation is equivalent to rotating in a fixed position, so as long as my modelling is concerned, I can just as well assume that the center of the measuring device is positioned at a random point in some disk around the origin and no rotation is allowed.

Comment: @Msegling As to uniform vs Gaussian, I would try to figure it out on a single sensor rather than on the full machine. Just mount it somewhere, place an obstacle in front of it and measure a few times. Note that we do not care about consistent bias (it will be cancelled by calibration), just about the distribution of the deviation from the mean, so you do not need to know the distance to the obstacle to perform this test. Once the machine is assembled, we will see only the average of 3 censors and that will be Gaussian no matter what the individual distributions are, so it will be too late...

Comment: Ive updated my question as promised. In my effort to grasp the concepts you presented, and show my interpretation of it, I have created a derivative of your solution. My hopes are that when I get confused that you can point to the exact point wheremy interpretation went wrong. I would like to focus on the statement that "C is inversely proportional to Λc" . I find myself disagreeing with this statement, as it appears to me that C should actually be directly proportional to Λc. Can you identify the source of my misconception?

Comment: @Msegling I tried to explain the inverse proportionality in an addition to my second answer (it was too long to fit into the comment box). Beyond what I wrote there I can only say that you can always try the numerical simulations to check the predictions of the theory if you disagree with them: there is no need to take anything on faith; just see if it agrees with simulations or not :-) I'll read the rest of your additions to the question post tomorrow and let you know what I think (probably in the same second answer box). BTW, if you want to establish a direct communication, just let me know.

Comment: Ahh! Yes that is a big oversight from me. Thank you for explaining! Of couse we can't have diverse measurements and a small Λc. I would love to have a Teams or Zoom call! Im sure that would benifit me immensely. Although I must warn you Im not sharpest pencil in the box... clearly obvious concepts (like the replationship between C and Λc) are not be so obvious to me. Here is my email: msegling@gmail.com

Answer (score 7):

Partial Answer

Let $x = a + r_{a}, y = b + r_{b}, z = c + r_{c}$. Then, the triangle formed by the three endpoints has side lengths $s_{c} = \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+xy},s_{a} = \sqrt{y^{2}+z^{2}+yz}, s_{b} = \sqrt{x^{2}+z^{2}+xz}$ using the Law of Cosines. Because the circumradius of the triangle is $\frac{D}{2}$, we can use the following identity:
$$\frac{D}{2} = \frac{s_{a}s_{b}s_{c}}{\sqrt{2s_{a}^{2}s_{b}^{2}+2s_{a}^{2}s_{c}^{2}+2s_{b}^{2}s_{c}^{2}-s_{a}^{4}-s_{b}^{4}-s_{c}^{4}}}$$
Simplifying:
$$2s_{a}^{2}s_{b}^{2}+2s_{a}^{2}s_{c}^{2}+2s_{b}^{2}s_{c}^{2}-s_{a}^{4}-s_{b}^{4}-s_{c}^{4}=\frac{4s_{a}^{2}s_{b}^{2}s_{c}^{2}}{D^{2}}$$
Substituting for $s_{a},s_{b},s_{c}$:
$$3x^{2}y^{2}+3x^{2}z^{2}+3y^{2}z^{2}+6x^{2}yz+6xy^{2}z+6xyz^{2}=\frac{4(x^2+y^2+xy)(x^2+z^2+xz)(y^2+z^2+yz)}{D^{2}}$$
If you further substitute for $x,y,z$, you obtain a big polynomial equation in the variables $r_{a},r_{b},r_{c}$. Using the three sets of measurements, it becomes a system of three polynomial equations in three variables, which can be numerically solved for $r_{a},r_{b},r_{c}$. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like symbolic methods will go any further as is. Assuming a specific value for $D$ and scaling back later might make some progress.

Answer (score 0):

Since I exceeded the character limit, I'll continue here.

***The more accurate  calibration diagnostics***

So far I tried to convince you that under the approximate model, the error in the determination of the radius $R$ is essentially bounded from above by the sum $(A+B\Lambda)\varepsilon$  where $A\varepsilon$ is the error in the estimate of the average $\frac{r_a+r_b+r_c}3$ and $B=C/4$ where $C\varepsilon$ is the error (3D vector) in the estimate of $(r_a-r_b, r_b-r_c, r_c-r_a)$, so, if we believe that, it becomes important to get tight bounds on $A,C$. Above I just got a bound on $C$ using the approximate equation and swept under the rug the bound on $A$. Now it is time to do everything carefully from the true equations $F(x,y,z)=0$.

First a bit of general theory of calibration. Suppose we want to determine the uncnown parameter vector $p$ ($(r_a,r_b,r_c)$ in our case) from the (possibly overdetermined) system of equations $\Phi(p,m_k)=0$ coming from $K$ vector measurements $m_k$ ($(a_k,b_k,c_k)$  in our case). Suppose we use something like the the least square method (which is our approach) and get an approximation $p$ while the true solution is $\bar p$. Suppose that each component of $m_k$ has an independent random error of size $\varepsilon$ (in my model that means uniform distribution on $[-\varepsilon, varepsilon]$, so the variance is $\frac{\varepsilon^2}3$, but for the purposes of this discussion, let us assume the Gaussian error with variance $\varepsilon^2$).

Then, if $E_k$ is the error in the measurement $m_k$ (a Gaussian vector with iid entries), the $k$-the equation at the true solution gets violated by, roughly speaking, $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial m}(\bar p)\cdot E_k$ ($\cdot$ stands for the scalar product here), which is just the Gaussian vector with the variance $\|\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial m}(\bar p,m_k)\|^2\varepsilon^2$. The least square method is trying to compensate that violation by shifting the parameter $\bar p$ by $dp$ (so $p=\bar p+dp$), which introduces the correction $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial m}(\bar p,m_k)\cdot dp$. Thus, the least square method is essentially solving the overdetermined system
$$
A\,dp=B
$$
where $A$ is the matrix of the partials with respect to parameters and $B$ is a Gaussian vector whose entries are independent and have variances $\|\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial m}(\bar p,m_k)\|^2\varepsilon^2$. The least square solution $dp$ is just
$$
(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB
$$
which is a Gaussian vector again with some fancy covariance. We may be in general interested in projecting $dp$ to various subspaces (like in our case where we are interested in the sum $r_a+r_b+r_c$ separately). Then, if $P$ is the orthogonal projection to the desired subspace, we can write $dp=P(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$ and use the information about the variances of the components of the Gaussian vector $B$ to figure out the distribution of the Gaussian vector $P\,dp$ from simple linear algebra. In general, if we apply the matrix $M$ to a Gaussian vector with variances of the components given by the squares of the entries of some vector $u$, then the expected square of the norm of the resulting vector will be just
$
\operatorname{Trace} M^Tuu^TM
$. Knowing that, we can estimate the probability that the actually observed norm will be above a certain value and make it as small as we want. For my predictors ,IIchose the probability of error about 1 in 1,000, which, for one-dimensional Gaussian corresponds to about 3 standard deviations. If you want to allow higher probability of error, you can go down a bit, but not too much: you are above 2 standard deviations with probability about 0.02, which, IMHO, is a bit too much: every 50-th calibration will be over the predictor instead of every thousandth now. On the other hand, if you want to lower the proabbility of error to $10^{-4}$, all you need to do is to use $4$ satndard deviations instead of $3$. For higher-dimensional vectors the cut-offs are even sharper. Of course, since we do not know $\bar p$, we'll have to plug in the approximation $p$  instead of it to determine the matrices, which, strictly speaking, introduces an extra error. Fortunately, this error is often much smaller and can be safely neglected in the majority of cases.

If you understand all that, the code below will not surprise you. The corresponding finction DIAG(a,b,c,ra,rb,rc,R) returns the (essentially guaranteed) pair of bounds (A,C) for the errors in the average and in the pairwise difference vector respectively (counted in $\varepsilon$'s). Once you know them, you know the  guaranteed bound $(A+C\Lambda/4)\varepsilon$ for the error in  the actual future measurements coming from the mistake in the calibration alone and can decide whether it is satisfactory or not. Note that while this is the guaranteed upper bound , the typical truth is about 1/5 of that upper bound. However, the chance that you are above 2/3 of this upper bound is 1 in 50 and the chance that you are above 1/3 of it is 1 in 5, so I would not try to use the typical value for the warranty purposes.

Now the code (aborediag.asy)

```
pair DIAG(real[] a, real[] b, real[] c, real ra, real rb, real rc, real R)
{
int K=a.length;
real[][] A;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)
{
real x=ra+a[k], y=rb+b[k], z=rc+c[k];
A[k]=new real[]{Fx(x,y,z,R),Fy(x,y,z,R),Fz(x,y,z,R)};
}


real[] U;

for(int k=0;k<K;++k) 
{
U[k]=0;
for(int j=0;j<3;++j) 
U[k]+=A[k][j]^2;
}


real[][] AA=inverse(transpose(A)*A)*transpose(A);

real[] Aa=(AA[0]+AA[1]+AA[2])/3;
real s=0;
for(int k=0;k<K;++k)  
s+=Aa[k]^2*U[k];

for(int k=0;k<3;++k) AA[k]-=Aa;

real ss=0;
for(int k=0;k<3;++k) 
for(int j=0;j<K;++j) 
ss+=AA[k][j]^2*U[k];


return (2*sqrt(s), 3.2*sqrt(ss));

}
```

***Measuring the true machine accuracy***

Since the bound for the absolute error in the measurement of the radius was given in terms of the true machine precision $\varepsilon$ (which I understood as the maximal individual sensor error for the uniform distribution, but which can also be understood as $\sqrt 3$ times the mean square error for the Gaussian distribution), it would be nice to be able to get an idea of what that $\varepsilon$ actually is during the calibration process. Note that the mean square error in the radius that the machine would produce given a perfect calibration ($r_a=Ra$, etc.) is $\varepsilon/3$. Unfortunately, the error introduced by the calibration will be a few times larger even if you calibrate and operate the machine at the same value of $\Lambda=\Lambda_c$ unless you want to go really high in the number $K$ of measurements. Even when $K=25$, the corresponding guaranteed calibration error is 3-4 times larger (though, as I said earlier, the expected value of the error introduced by the calibration is about 1/5 to 1/4 of that maximum, so quite often you'll really calibrate the machine essentially to its theoretical capacity but you'll not be able to guarantee it). Thus, it is reasonable to expect that essentially the whole error in the future measurements will be due to the calibration error rather than to the true capability of the sensors and if you want to bring the resulting error of the machine measurements to the specification $\varepsilon_s$, you will need to ensure the inequality $(A+B\Lambda)\varepsilon<\varepsilon_s$ (the measurement error due to the wrong calibration is not distributed as a Gaussian; instead, the $A$ part provides the constant bias and the $B$ part is essentially distributed like a multiple of $\cos t$ for the uniform distribution of $t$ on $[0,2\pi]$, so the typical values are more towards the ends than towards the middle and the mean square error in the random position on the circle corresponding to the given $\Lambda$ is $\varepsilon\sqrt{A^2+\frac 12 B^2\Lambda^2}$. So you would like to make sure that your true machine error $\varepsilon$ is a few times smaller than the required specification $\varepsilon_s$ to produce a calibrated machine that would meet the specification.

The unbiased in the sence of the mean square estimate for $\varepsilon$ is just $\bar\varepsilon=3\sqrt{\frac{K}{K-3}}G(r_a,r_b,r_c)$ where $r_a,r_b,r_c$ are the values the calibration produces. If this estimate already exceeds the specified $\varepsilon_s$, the case is pretty hopeless. But if it is several times smaller, it may still be due to the pure luck up to $15$ or so measurements. We are essentially talking about the concentration of the sum of $K-3$ squares of the independent Gaussian variables here. If they are standard, then the mean of the square is $1$ and the variance is $2$ (the fourth moment of $3$ minus the second moment squared $1^2$. Thus, for $K-3$ Gaussiand we'll play the mean $K-3$ against the variance $\sqrt{2(K-3)}$ and if we use the same 3 STD standard, we will need $(K-3)^2\ge 18(\frac 43)^2(K-3)=32(K-3)$ to be sure that $\bar\varepsilon\in[\varepsilon/2,3\varepsilon/2]$ with probability $0.999$. This calles for 35 measurements at least. However, the value of knowing the true machine $\varepsilon$ should, probably, outweigh the hustle of making so many measurements. If you use a relaxed 2 STD standard (erring 1 time in 50), you can lower the measurement number about twice to 16. It is up to you (or your boss) to decide what probability of unnoticed bad situation one can tolerate. I just want to make clear how to compute this probability based on $K$ and the data, so if somebody complains about bad machine performance later, you would be always able to say that they had a fair warning. :lol:

That formally almost wraps it up except for a few points about testing the algorithm etc. I intend to post all the codes I used with comments what I have changed from the original versions and how to use them, so that you can run all  my current programs and compare the results with your own simulations. Of course, I'll be interested in seeing the real data to see what is going on with them. Waiting for a couple of months is not a problem. If you want to fine tune some features and parameters of my algorithms to the typical data you expect to run them on, I'd appreciate knowing a few things:

1. What is the typical ratio of $\varepsilon_s/R$?
2. What is a typical $\Lambda$ you expect to use in the calibration and the measurements?
3. How large $K$ are you willing to afford during the calibration?

That is all that comes to my mind today. Keep looking at this thread for updates and, if you have some questions or concerns, by all means voice them. :-)

***it appears to me that C should actually be directly proportional to $\Lambda_c$***

I'll try to explain the inverse proportionality in 2 ways.

The first one is just formal. We've seen that in the exactly solvable approximate model $C$ is just the square root of the norm (or the trace, no big difference in $\mathbb R^2$) of $(A^TA)^{-1}$, so the more degenerate the matrix becomes, the larger $C$ should be. But small $\Lambda_c$ forces all the rows to be almost exactly the same (if we take all observations from the dead center, i.e., $\Lambda_c=0$, they will be just exactly the same up to the measurement error), so, as we diminish $\Lambda_c$, we are closer and closer to the rank 1 case for $A$ which is as degenerate as it can be without having the entire matrix tend to $0$. Thus there should be a blow up of $C$ as $\Lambda_c\to 0$, not an improvement.

The second explanation is that as we have seen in the approximate model, the error in the determination of $R$ for fixed correct sum $r_a+r_b+r_c$ is proportional to $\Lambda$ times the norm of the error in the vector $(r_a-r_b,r_b-r_c,r_c-r_a)$ (we estimated the latter by $C\varepsilon$). This is easy to verify numerically for the true formula for the radius too: just take some values $R_a,R_b,R_c$ and $r_a,r_b,r_c$ with the same sum but otherwise different and watch the error as you move your position away from the center (determine the measurements by the position and $R$'s and recompute with $r$'s. That means that the sensitivity of the *measurements* to the error in the parameters is directly proportional to $\Lambda$. But then the sensitivity of parameters with respect to the errors in the measurements should be *inversely* proportional to $\Lambda_c$ because you have to move the parameter vector a lot for small $\Lambda$ for compensate for the fixed size measurement error. Think of $K=3$ where the compensation can be made perfect more often than not. This is just the general common sense reciprocity principle applicable to pretty much everything. Say, while it takes a big shift in the public behavior to inflict a small change in the government policies, a small direct change in the policies initiated by the government creates a big shift in people's behavior when they try to adjust their lives to compensate for it.

The confusion, most likely, stemmed from the absolutely correct observation that if we are at the dead center *and know it*, we can easily recover $r_a$ as $R-a$, etc. However, if we don't know a priori that we are at the dead center, somebody else can assume that we are at absolutely any different position with some $x,y,z$ and declare that $r_a$ is actually $x-a$ instead. There is no way to tell which one of you two is right because both of you have explained the observed measurement perfectly. Thus, to distinguish, we want to diversify the measurement position as much as possible, which means moving away off the center as much as we can. Ideally, if we were allowed to rotate, we should just get away from the center to some fixed point and do $K$ equispaced rotations from there. Without rotation, the equivalent set of measurements would be from equidistant points (vertices of a regular $K$-gon) on the circle of radius $\Lambda_c R$ with as large $\Lambda_c$ as one can afford. I suspect that in reality all you can arrange is a random position within the disk of radius $\Lambda_c R$ and that is what I'm currently using in my simulations for the measurements.